# Apply class to the a tag link generated in post tag links

Tags: tags

I'm using the following code to generate tags

```
<?php if( has_tag() ): ?>
<?php echo '<div id="tagWrapper">'?><p>Tags</p><?php the_tags('<ul class="tags"><li class="tag-body olive">','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?><?php echo '</div>' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's output is an unordered list with simple `<a>` links. I need to apply a class to these links `class="tag-body olive`

What file is generating these tags I looked in my themes functions.php

Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer, that's the code you need to use, not the one earlier.

Comment: I ended up applying the style to the `li` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`get_the_tags();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) is probably what you are looking for. The following code displays a list of tags with links to each one and a specific class for each tag:

```
<?php
    $tags = get_the_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);

        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
?>
```

Now, using that logic, I've modified your code to do what you want:

```
<?php if( has_tag() ) { ?>
    <div id="tagWrapper">

        <p>Tags</p>

        <?php
        $tags = get_the_tags();
        $html = '<ul class="tags">';
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
            $html .= "<li class="tag-body olive"><a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
            $html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        echo $html;
        ?>

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And the output in case it helps (although untested) should look like this:

```
<div id="tagWrapper">
    <p>Tags</p>
    <ul class="tags">
        <li class="tag-body olive">
            <a href='http://example.com/tag/technology/' title='Technology Tag' class='technology'>Technology</a>
        </li>

        <li class="tag-body olive">
            <a href='http://example.com/tag/gadgets/' title='Gadgets Tag' class='gadgets'>Gadgets</a>
        </li>

        <li class="tag-body olive">
            <a href='http://example.com/tag/mobile/' title='Mobile Tag' class='mobile'>Mobile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**SOURCE:** [WordPress Codex Function Reference for `get_the_tags();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)

Comment: just be aware that `get_tags()` will get the tags from the site; while `get_the_tags()` would get tags from the post - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Comment: @Michael Thanks for spotting the mistake. Corrected! Oops moment!

Answer (score 0):

```
/****post-tag****/
function asr_tags() { 
    $asrtags =  get_the_tags();
    foreach($asrtags as $tag){
        $string .= '<span class="post-tag"><a class="p-tag" href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name . '</a></span>' . "\n"   ;
    } 
    return $string;
} 
add_shortcode('asrtags' , 'asr_tags' );

/*****post-tag*****/
```

Comment: Can you please also add explanation what your code does?

Comment: @Innate

where is the mistake?
i use this in my wp function.php
but when i chake my file manager then show in error log, buT still working this code.


PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 3

Comment: Please use the [edit link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344374/edit) below your answer if you would like to add further information. Usually code only answer are not as well received without an explanation backing what the code does and how the code solves the original question.

Comment: brother already solve the code